# RouteServiceProvider::boot() laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel

I am developing a web application by Laravel 5.6, and when I I wrote 'php artisan serve' and I got an error bellow.

> In LaravelShopProvider.php line 130:
>    Declaration of Amsgames\LaravelShop\LaravelShopProvider::boot(Illuminate\Routing\Router $router) should be compatib
>     le with Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::boot()

This is my boot function in RouteServiceProvider.php file

```
public function boot()
{
    /*
     * Register route model bindings
     */

    /*
     * This allows us to use the Route Model Binding with SoftDeletes on
     * On a model by model basis
     */
    $this->bind('deletedUser', function ($value) {
        $user = new User();

        return User::withTrashed()->where($user->getRouteKeyName(), $value)->first();
    });


    parent::boot();

}
```

Comment: I tried this answers but it dosn't work